# не закрывает процесс

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть основная программа, которая при определенном условии запускает второй exe'шник, который должен в свою очередь закрыть основную программу, обновить ее и запустить заново.

Метод основной программы, запускающий второй exe'шник

```
private void GetProductVersion()
        {
            int currentVersion = Convert.ToInt32(Application.ProductVersion.Replace(".", ""));
            int versionRemote = 0;
            string queryProductVersion = String.Format("select \"file_ver\" from dbo.AutoUpdates where \"file_ver\" = '1.0.0.41'");
            var loadData = cs.LoadFile("DataConnection.xml");
            string connString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3}", loadData.Host, loadData.Database, loadData.UserId, loadData.PWD);
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryProductVersion, conn))
                {
                    versionRemote = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(".", ""));
                }
            }
            if (currentVersion < versionRemote)
            {
                Process.Start(@"D:\Projects\Doc\Update\bin\Debug\Update.exe");
            }
        }
```

Второй exe'шник, в котором пытаюсь закрыть основную программу

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("FirstApp.exe"))
                {
                    proc.Kill();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Полный путь также пробовал прописывать для `GetProcessesByName`, но программу не закрывает. Чисто для теста пробовал по нажатию кнопки запускать снова основную программу - запускает. На закрытие почему-то не работает.
Где я ошибся?

Comment: А зачем закрывать программу из второго экзешника? Почему бы просто не закрыть себя сразу после `Process.Start(...)`?

Comment: Почему не используете ClickOnce? Там это уже реализовано.

Comment: @rdorn в ClickOnce проблема с сохранением настроек программы после первого захода, после обновления они слетают и нужно заново вводить их. Решил частично эту проблему, добавив в публикацию файл с настройками, в нем содержится Connection String для подключения к базе данных и последний залогинившийся пользователь. Но если пользователь будет другой в момент обновления программы, слетят и настройки под него. Так как файл, который добавлен в публикацию, не изменяется же

Comment: @tym32167 хорошая мысль, даже не подумал) Но все же интересно, почему процесс не закрывается с другого exe'шника

Comment: по мне так проще допилить правильное сохранение настроек, ну тут уже вам решать.

Comment: @rdorn я добавил в публикацию xml-файл с настройками, но это не главная проблема, когда я делаю новую версию публикации и перезахожу в приложение оно не обновляет его автоматически почему-то, а нужно с ftp-сервера (куда я публикую) выкачивать папку и через апликейшен обновлять. В чем прикол, не пойму

Comment: там в настройках есть галочка специальная, чуть позже могу выложить скрины с настройками, если такой вариант интересен.Наше приложение обновляется автоматом при запуске после каждой публикации.

Comment: @rdorn буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Просто не используйте расширение исполняемого файла (.exe) при поиска процесса.

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("FirstApp")
```

[docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8) :

> Имя процесса — это понятное имя процесса, например Outlook, которое не включает расширение EXE или путь.

Comment: так тоже пробовал и увы, не закрывает